# To call a function, from another class to Activity Class in ANDROID

Tags: android, class, function, variables, android-activity

I've written my codes and functions only in an activity class(A).
Then I moved a function from activity class to new java class(B). 
and I extend it like this

```
public class B extends A{

    int sum=0;
    public int funcSum(){
       int x=5;
       sum=sum+x;
       return sum;
     };
```

And this is my activity class:

```
            public class A extends Activity {

                final B c = new B();
                TextView1.setText("sum= " + new Integer(c.funcSum()).toString());
```

When I execute it, it does not give a codeline error. But it always shows sum=0 .
as I see it does not calculate sum in the function of 'funcSum'.

Comment: This code should work. It is not clear why you extend A, but. By the way. where do you place such code? in onCreate()?

Comment: This should not make a difference but on class B use this.sum += x; return this.sum;

Comment: Vladimir Ivanov, my codes(A) is in onCreate().

Comment: NeTeInStEiN, still doesnt work :S

Comment: @Dapina, please add some more code.

Comment: and also, try to remove `final` from `final B c = new B();`

Comment: MByD, I've tried but still shows sum=0...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "new Integer()".  Try just "c.funcSum().toString()".

Comment: You cannot convert `int` to String using `toString` method. `int` is a primitive.

Comment: @Dapina - Generally, you can simply write `TextView1.setText("sum= " + c.funcSum());`. but please read my comments on your question as well

Comment: You're going to have to post more code then.  It's not likely that the issue you've outline above is causing the problem.